# Problem with ppa:barracuda72/ralink repository

Tags: ppa, launchpad, ralink

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS. My WiFi/Bluetooth card is of ralink. When I installed wireless driver the barracuda ppa was added(unchecked) and I enabled(checked) them as follows:

[image]

Now, the problem is when I run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

in terminal the output is as follows:

```
Ign http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty InRelease                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease 
Hit http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release     
Hit http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/main Sources
Hit http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/universe Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net trusty/universe Translation-en_US
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/barracuda72/ralink/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/barracuda72/ralink/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That PPA doesn't exist for 'Trusty', just for 'Raring'.

Try to replace 'trusty' with 'raring' for distribution. Just select PPA in 'Software & Updates' (your image) than click 'Edit...' and write 'raring' (without quotes) under 'Distribution'. Do this for 'Source Code' PPA also.

After that

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install what you need. Probably will work everything you install but without guarantee.

Comment: It works.Thanks. What actually the trusty and raring mean?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 is named Raring Ringtail and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is named Trusty Tahr, so repositories has suffix according to Ubuntu version (raring, trusty...).

Comment: That means I've configured the repository for Ubuntu 13.04. Will it work for Ubuntu 14.04 to download softwares?

Comment: Software is not the problem in most cases, but drivers and stuff like that can be tricky...