# Ubuntu 14.04 bluetooth adapter no found

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, bug-reporting

So, I've a HP 4540(H6R10EA) and my bluetooth is working fine under Windows 8.1, but when running Ubuntu 14.04(I've a dual boot) I can't enable it. I tried searching on the forums, but none of the solutions worked for me. I typed in some commands in terminal and the output is down bellow, I hope it helps.

```
rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
02:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
02:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
02:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller (rev 30)
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)

sudo lsmod |grep blue 
bluetooth             391136  10 bnep,rfcomm
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your Bluetooth driver for your Ralink device (Ralink RT3290) has a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1189721) similar to your problem.

[This Ubuntu fourm post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2115570) seems to have the solution.

Make an out-of-the-way directory

```
mkdir ~/bluetooth
cd ~/bluetooth
```

Download this driver that apparently works

```
wget http://downloads.zotac.com/mediadrivers/mb/download/NB087_Ubuntu.zip
```

Unzip it

```
unzip NB087_Ubuntu.zip
```

Untar the Bluetooth driver

```
tar jxzf NB087_BT_ubuntu_release.tar.bz2
```

I'm not sure on the following because I'm on a mobile device

Hunt around for a readme or similar document, it will give you instructions to install the driver, hopefully

One installed, make this script

```
gksu gedit ~/bluetooth/bluetooth.sh
```

Insert this code into that script file

```
#!/bin/bash
insmod rtbth.ko 
mknod /dev/rtbth c 192 0 
./path/to/the/file/rtbt.bin 
exit 0
```

Save that code and add executable privileges

```
chmod +x bluetooth.sh
```

Now, with a bit of luck, you can run it, and have working Bluetooth

```
./bluetooth.sh
```

If it works, then just set that script to run at boot up

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

And add (Your Name = username)

```
sh /home/YourName/bluetooth/bluetooth.sh
```

...before the return 0 in the file

The Bluetooth should start up each boot up now

Comment: I tried installing rtbth-dkms package by adding ppa:barracuda72/ralink repo, but I get this                           W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/barracuda72/ralink/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/barracuda72/ralink/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/barracuda72/ralink/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Did you run ``sudo apt-get update`` after adding the new repository?

Comment: the code in my comment is from sudo apt-get update, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: after reading [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520939/problem-with-ppabarracuda72-ralink-repository) post I changed barracuda72 repo from trusty to raring and not sudo apt-get update works, but when I try sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms I get E: Unable to locate package rtbth-dkms.

Comment: Just added my understanding of answer that seemed to work from the link. Sorry its not complete, Im on a mobile device, so no tarball unpacking for me

Comment: I tried your solution, and reading the installation notes from Ubuntu RT3290 Bluetooth Host Driver User Guide.pdf in the folder `sudo modprobe bluetooth` and after `sudo insmod rtbth.ko` I get `insmod: ERROR: could not load module rtbth.ko: No such file or directory`, so no bluetooth for now.

Comment: Seems it cant find ``rtbth.ko``, do the extracted files contain a directory or two? Maybe its hiding in one of the folders (if there are any)

Comment: Nope, no `rtbth.ko` unfortunately.

Comment: Well that's annoying, sorry I couldn't help you. I wish you luck finding a working driver. If not, Ubuntu do know about the bug, so expect to see a bug fix soonish.

Comment: Yea, it's a well known bug. Looks like I'm going to be using my bluetooth mouse with the usb plug that comes with it :)

Answer (score 0):

try this...to get your BT adapter recognized.
System is a Dell XFR E6420 laptop with a Broadcom 370 BCM2046B1 Bluetooth card installed.  I have two Solid State hard drives, one with Windows 7 and the other with Ubuntu 14.04.  Neither Windows or Ubuntu recognized the BT card at first.  However, after installing the broadcom drivers on windows 7, it was recognized and worked fine.  Then once it was "turned ON" in windows, the system was shut down, the Ubuntu 14.04 hard drive was installed and booted.  Now the Broadcom BCM2046B1 Bluetooth card is recognized by Ubuntu 14.04 and works fine.  I re-tested this by booting windows again and turning the card "OFF", subsequently Ubuntu did not recognize the card.  It has to be "turned ON" in windows first, then Ubuntu sees it.
I tried this after hours of 'fun' reading and trying all the fixes, so save yourself some aggravation and give this a try first.

Comment: Can you please make your answer clearer? It is hard to follow through.

Answer (score 0):

After hours trying fix after fix from these forums, it seems the I could switch on bluetooth by pressing and holding the blue 'fn' button and pressing 'F3' which has the corresponding blue wifi symbol.

I was overjoyed when that brought up the bluetooth icon next to my clock and i was able to switch on bluetooth.

Unfortunately pressing the 'fn' + 'F3' enabled bluetooth but DISABLED WIFI.

It seems I can only toggle between bluetooth OR wifi not both on at the same time.

This problem has only occured since I re-installed Bluez.