# Ubuntu restarts after shutdown

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, bug-reporting

I've a problem with my laptop(HP 4540s H6R10EA) that doesn't want to shut down under Ubuntu 14.04. It shut downs and after 2 secs starts again.

Tried everything that I could find online: unchecked bios settings like start on LAN or USB, `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and editing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. The problem most likely came from my efforts to enable Bluetooth,

I've another [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522295/ubuntu-14-04-bluetooth-adapter-no-found) from today actually, tried to purge the rtbth package and unblock the default driver to return to it(by the way `rfkill list` returns nothing and it used to give me at least my wireless card). I've Windows 8.1 dual booting and when I switch to it I can shut down my laptop and it doesn't start again, so it must come from my Ubuntu OS and close from reinstalling it, becaust it was working yesterday(ok my bluetooth wasn't but I see this is a common issue with RT3290 wireless card).

Comment: You are not alone. I have noticed it happens when it is running on battery only. On AC, it shutdown properly. How about you? Running Xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Well for me it was while the battery was plugged in and charging on AC. I installed Ubuntu again and now it's running ok, however I'm not even trying to make my bluetooth work again :)