# Bluetooth RT3290 "no Bluetooth adapters found"

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, additional-drivers

My wifi is working well but bluetooth is not working. It notifies me "No Bluetooth adapters found".

[image: OUTPUT1]
[image: OUTPUT2]
[image: OUTPUT3]
[image: OUTPUT4]
[image: OUTPUT5]
[image: OUTPUT6]

If any more command outputs etc are needed, please let me know and I will provide them.

Comment: You need to show what is the problem. You can't connect to bluetooth or something?

Comment: @thangdc94 my wifi is working well but bluetooh is not working. it nofiy me "No adapter found".

Comment: Please post output of `sudo lsmod |grep blue` and output of `systemctl status bluetooth.service`

Comment: @thangdc94 i added.

Comment: As output of `lsmod` you didn't install module bluetooth. Please check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522295/ubuntu-14-04-bluetooth-adapter-no-found)

Comment: @thangdc94 it was hard but tried and didn't work. i am not an expert, it is too low-level for me.  But btw thanks.

Comment: Try the bpatch script from https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E  I have no idea if it works correctly or not

Comment: @Jeremy31 thanks your help but i tried that one please check issues :)

Comment: What does `modinfo btusb | egrep 'file|verm'` show?  Add results by editing the question

Comment: Sorry you have the 3290, that github won't help

Answer (score 0):

I found something that may work

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms
```

Reboot

Comment: Check results for `lsmod | grep blue` is btusb still loading?

Comment: output is nothing.